# Nested loop is ignoring other elements

Tags: javascript

I'm writing Js script that simply excludes elements from array `a` if the element is in array `b`:

```
const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];
let new_array = [];
for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
 for (let z = 0; z < b.length; z++) {
    if (a[x] !== b[z]) {
     //console.log(a[x]);
     new_array.push(a[x]);
     }
  }
}
return new_array;
```

Running this 11 is excluded but 4 isn't. What gives ?

Comment: 4 is included because, when x = 2 and z = 1, a[2] !== b[1]

Comment: Actually, both `11` and `4` will be in the results, and the others will be there twice: `[1, 1, 22, 22, 11, 4]`.  Your basic logic is a problem.  For each element of `b`, you add the current element of `a` if it doens't match `b`.  Look at `Array.prototype.some`, or `contains`.  Also look at `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

let result = a.filter(item => !b.includes(item));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm starting to like ES6 more and more.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are comparing not only the value but it's position in the array. Try changing your condition to this:

```
(!b.contains(a[x]))
```

Edit: that also means you can get rid of the inner loop. Only loop through the 'a' array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

const result = a.filter( el => b.indexOf( el ) < 0 );

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

const new_array = a.filter( element1 => {
  return !b.some( element2 => element2 == element1 );
});

console.log(new_array); // outputs [1, 22]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qfw6ep5L/

Answer (score 0):

## Step-by-step tranformation

This is an attempt to show how to move from the style in your initial attempt to the more expressive and elegant solution in the answer from Sohail.  We will continually refine a single function so that it continues to work but becomes cleaner and easier to understand as we go.

### Fixing the problem

First we need to fix the issue raised by this question.  As I pointed out in a comment, the trouble is that you were doing something like this:

> ```
> Hmm, we have a = [1, 22, 11, 4] and b = [11, 4].  
> We should start by creating an empty array.          (new_array = [])
> Let's see, does 1 == 11?  No?  Add it to the output. (new_array = [1])  
> Does 1 == 4?  No?  Add it to the output.             (new_array = [1, 1])  
> Does 22 == 11?  No?  Add it to the output.           (new_array = [1, 1, 22])  
> Does 22 == 4?  No?  Add it to the output.            (new_array = [1, 1, 22, 22])  
> Does 11 == 11? Yes?  Skip it.                        (new_array = [1, 1, 22, 22])  
> Does 11 == 4? No?  Add it to the output.             (new_array = [1, 1, 22, 22, 11])  
> Does 4 == 11? No?  Add it to the output              (new_array = [1, 1, 22, 22, 11, 4])  
> Does 4 == 4? Yes?  Skip it.                          (new_array = [1, 1, 22, 22, 11, 4])  
> All right.  Let's return that value: [1, 1, 22, 22, 11, 4]  
> Great job, team!
> ```

To fix this, we need to keep track of whether our `a` value has been found inside `b`.  Here's a version which does this:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < a .length; x++) {
    let found = false;
    for (let z = 0; z < b .length; z++) {
      if (a [x] == b [z]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      new_array .push (a [x]);
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### Cleaning up the nasty loop

The `break` statement allow us to avoid further testing all the other values once we've found one that matches.  When we need a `break` in a loop, it's often a sign that there's something wrong with our technique.  Here methods of the [Array Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) offer a cleaner approach.

One of the first things I teach those trying to move from novice to intermediate programmers is to replace at least 90% of the `for`-loops they write with something more appropriate.  Array methods such as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and, if necessary, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) all make more explicit what we're trying to do in a loop.  The vast majority of times, one of them is appropriate.

Here our inner loop is just used to find if there is *some* value in `b` which matches our current test value.  [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is designed exactly for that.  It takes a predicate function (one which returns `true` or `false`) and checks the values of the array until it finds one for which the function returns `true`.  If none of them do, it returns `false`.  That's exactly what we're trying to do with our inner loop and the `found` variable.  So we can rewrite it like this:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < a .length; x++) {
    if ( !(b .some (val => a [x] == val))) {
      new_array .push (a [x])
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}
```

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < a .length; x++) {
    if ( !(b .some (val => a [x] == val))) {
      new_array .push (a [x])
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### Using `includes`

When the predicate passed to `some` just tests whether a value is equal to another as we have here, we're essentially testing whether the array *includes* a particular value. 
 There is a slight clean-up in using the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function instead.  It has the same sort of behavior, but is slightly simpler.

So we could write this instead:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < a .length; x++) {
    if (!b .includes (a [x])) {
      new_array .push (a [x])
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}
```

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < a .length; x++) {
    if (!b .includes (a [x])) {
      new_array .push (a [x])
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### The advantages of `filter`

The remaining `for`-loop is doing one job.  It's *filtering* the input list to keep only those without a match.  So that is probably better expressed with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).  `filter` also takes a predicate and creates a new array containing only those values for which the predicate returns `true`.  This gives us a substantial clean-up:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))
  return new_array;
}
```

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  let new_array = a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))
  return new_array;
}

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### Removing intermediate variable

While that solution is fine, there is something to be said for removing the `new_array` variable.  Anytime a variable is used only in the line after it's defined, there is a real chance that the code will be equally clean if we inline it in the next line.  This is especially true if the next line is simply a `return`.  So we can simplify with this:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  return a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))
}
```

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) => {
  return a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))
}

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### Simpler arrow function

When the body of an arrow function contains only a `return`-expression, there is a further simplification we can use.  `(...args) => {return expression}` can also be written as `(...args) => expression`.  There is no need for the curly braces or the `return`.  This is very much a matter of individual style.  There are those who always want the `return`.  I personally am in the other camp, preferring to work with expressions instead of statements as much as possible.  So we can choose to write it like this:

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) =>
  a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))
```

```js
const aWithoutB = (a, b) =>
  a .filter (val => !(b .includes (val)))

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (aWithoutB (a, b));
```

### Naming

It has been said that, "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."  ([*Phil Karlton*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)).  Our name for this function does not feel right.  `aWithoutB` ties the function to the parameter *names*, which feels quite odd.  If we were to look around, we might see that [several](https://underscorejs.org/#difference) [major](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference) [libraries](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference) all have a version of this function, using the name `difference`.  This is meant to invoke the mathematical notion of set differences, namely the elements included in  one set not included in another.

Similarly, a convention I like is to use `x` and `y` for parameters of an arbitrary type, and `xs` and `ys` to represent an array of them.

So, for a final fix, we might rename our function:

```js
const difference = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .filter (x => !(ys .includes (x)))
```

```js
const difference = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .filter (x => !(ys .includes (x)))

const a = [1, 22, 11, 4];
const b = [11,4];

console .log (difference (a, b));
```

### Lessons

The main take-away from this is that there are often useful abstractions available to clean up our low-level code.  It's fairly easy to read that final version at a glance and understand what it does.  Not only that, this is **easier** to write than the plain loop version.  I wrote that final version first, and quickly.  It was easy to see that it was correct.  Finding the error in the original code and writing a fix took significantly longer.

There are times for low-level code.  If performance is critical, a plain `for`-loop will usually beat one of these `Array.prototype` methods.  But we're better off writing clean, easily maintainable code and only dropping down to the lower levels when the code in question is a bottleneck in our application.  Ninety nine times out of a hundred, higher level code is the better bet.